# Does a using block count as a reference to the IDisposable it captures?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Suppose I have defined the followed method.

```
static object F()
{
    return new object();
}
```

If I write code like the following, the returned `object` cannot be garbage collected until the end of the scope.

```
{
    object x = F();
    // cannot yet garbage collect the object
    // returned by F (referenced as variable x)
}
// can now garbage collect the object
// returned by F (referenced as variable x)
```

If I write code like the following, the returned `object` can be garbage collected immediately after `F` returns.

```
{
    F();
    // can now garbage collect the object
    // returned by F
}
```

But now suppose I change the definition of `F` to the following.

```
static IDisposable F()
{
    return new SomeDisposableObject();
}
```

If I write code like the following, the returned object cannot be garbage collected and will not be disposed until the end of the `using` block.

```
using (IDisposable x = F())
{
} // immediately x.Dispose()
// can now garbage collect the object
// returned by F
```

**If I write code like the following, what is the behavior?** References to C# language specification are a plus.

```
using (F())
{
}
```

Does the `using` block count as a reference to the instance returned by `F`?

Comment: You are wrong about the scope and garbage collection. If you're no longer using the variable, it can be collected right away. This assumes you're running a RELEASE build outside of the debugger though.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Not so. If there were weird side effects in a custom finalizer (for a devilish example, maybe writing to a database table from a finalizer - not something I'm endorsing!), then when the garbage collector is allowed to do its job has to be very strictly defined. If there is still a variable somewhere referencing an instance, it cannot be garbage collected.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. A local variable that is no longer in use does not count as a root any more.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Do you have a language reference?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, but I don't think you'll find one either. The language specification will deal with the *syntactical scope* of the variable, not with the lifetime of the memory it references. If the variable is no longer used, it will in fact no longer count. I'll provide a LINQPad program you can experiment with so you can see for yourself.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Okay, thanks. This seems odd but I'm not too inclined to doubt you.

Comment: While I write the LINQPad program, you can examine the real need for [GC.KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx) if simply declaring a variable was enough to keep the memory it references alive for the duration of the method.

Comment: Try these two LINQPad programs: [Single object](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1z7w8c0nvspgyc/SO17886734A.linq), and the [result of debugging and a loop variable](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kfnvvxsp6x7gh4s/SO17886734B.linq). You should go get the latest [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) to execute these.

Comment: For an admittedly contrived example, which is incorrectly implemented to boot, here's an example of what can go wrong: [Fishing out sub-object and no longer having a "live" reference to the main object](https://www.dropbox.com/s/of7y9seeprcm0tu/SO17886734C.linq). In this case, `obj1` will not count as a live reference, so the main object will be collected, disposing the stream, even though the stream is actually still "in use". Note again, this is buggy code, but I've seen it in production code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

You cannot dispose something without a reference to it.

The spec [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736) that `using (expression) { statement }` is compiled to:

```
{
   ResourceType resource = expression;
   try {
      statement;
   }
   finally {
      if (resource != null) ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
   }
}
```

`resource` is a reference.

Comment: This was of course my suspicion, I just didn't know where to look to verify it. The link to MSDN settles it. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit reference to a local variable at the end of a scope. An implementation may, but is not required to, garbage collect an object after your last actual reference to it. In other words, your second code block is *not correct*, because `x` *is* allowed to be collected before the end of the block.

```
{
    object x = F();
    // <-- x IS ALLOWED to be collected here
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    // <-- The object x ref'd IS ALLOWED to be collected here, if it wasn't earlier
}
// <-- The object x ref'd IS ALLOWED to be collected here, if it wasn't earlier
```

A using block creates a local variable in order to call `Dispose` at the end of the using block. Even if you do not explicitly name the variable, the reference will be alive until the end of the block.

```
using (F())
{
    // The instance returned by F IS NOT allowed to be collected here
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    // The instance returned by F IS NOT allowed to be collected here
}
// The instance returned by F IS allowed to be collected here
```

Comment: Yes I think the fact you're saying about "last use of variable" versus "end of scope containing variable" is what I had wrong and was causing  me confusion.